# How to split timestamp field into Year, Month and Day, etc?

Tags: ibm-cloud, spss-modeler

I have a timestamp field which has this definition:

> Time interval: the beginning of the time interval expressed as the
>   number of millisecond elapsed from the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970
>   at UTC. The end of the time interval can be obtained by adding 600000
>   milliseconds (10 minutes) to this value. TYPE: numeric

I would like to split this field into Year, Month, Day of Month, Day of Week, Week Number.

It appears that I would need to use a Derive field with a Formula.  But as a user new to the SPSS world, it isn't clear to me how I would use the derive field to do this.

The equivalent in pandas is:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time interval'].astype(int))

df['Year'] = df['Datetime'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['Datetime'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['Datetime'].dt.day
df['DayOfWeek'] = df['Datetime'].dt.dayofweek
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create the 5 variables in separate, right?

For create:

**1) Year - Use a derive node and call the new variable as 'Year' with the syntax: "datetime_year(field)" -> will extract the year in  numbers (2012)

2) Month- Use a derive node and call the new variable as 'Month' with the syntax: "datetime_month(field)" -> will extract the month in numbers (1 to 12)

3) Day of Month- Use a derive node and call the new variable as 'DayMonth' with the syntax: "datetime_day(field)" -> will extract the date of the month in numbers (1 to 31)

4) Day of Week - Use a derive node and call the new variable as 'DayWeek' with the syntax: "datetime_weekday(field)" -> will extract the weekday in numbers (1 to 7)

5) Week Number - Use a derive node and call the new variable as 'WeekNumb' with the syntax: "date_iso_week(field)" -> ISO 8601 (it's the only function that I never used in your list).**

Also, you can check others expressions inside the derive node tab, just select all functions and make some tests.

[IBM Ref](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_17.0.0/clementine/derive_overview.html)

I hope to have been helpful.